# Synchronize in php or zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, synchronize

Is PHP has synchronize mechanism like Java? In my project different users can continue with same transaction.

As example, I send a mail with payment details page URL to different user. So they can view that page at same time. Also they can continue to same transaction. I want deny (Show message) that page for users when one user already view the page. In java we can use synchronize for object. How can i do it in php or zend framework?

Answer (score 3):

PHP is NOT like Java.

Each request run in a separate stack with separate variables. You can share objects in PHP only using extension like **memcache** etc.

My advise is to use the locking mechanism of the file system. For example:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen( $filename,"w"); // open it for WRITING ("w")
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    // do your stuf here
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // unlock the file
} else {
    // flock() returned false, no lock obtained
    print "Could not lock $filename!\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I can lock it. But user may be close the tab. So we can't unlock that process. It'll lock for ever. How it handle?

Comment: Aaaarghhh! The only thing worse than passing parameters via the session is using files as a database

Comment: @symcbean it is used solely for locking, no data is to be stored.

Comment: @Asuraya in that case I recommend to setup a locking mechanism base at timestamps. You can lock the page if someone else locked the page in the past 30 seconds and didn't logged out. Be notice that you should send to the server a "keep a live" requests every few seconds by AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve here - either in PHP or Java. It seems you want to apply a mutex to a dataset - however that's not a side effect of synchronized - not it's purpose. It shoudn't be necessary if you use the session id and a FSM to control access.