# How to determine if instance of function is in process of executing?

Tags: php, function, detection, execution

How to determine if instance of function is in process of executing?

Notes:

-I'm aware of solution with logging to DB when function_started and function_ended, but problem I can't solve then is: if function is terminated during execution log will be incorrect.

-general problem that I'm solving is: in multi user web app - one function should be used by one user at a time, so before executing checking is required if some instance of function is already running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191317/synchronize-in-php-or-zend-framework

Answer (score 0):

May be the question was not formulated well, but I founded the answer I was looking for here:
PHP semaphores http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-semaphores